# USB Debugging Moverio on Mac

Tags: android, adb

I have just go a Moverio BT-100, Epson seem as much use as a paper bag.  Has anyone managed to get USB Debugging / ADB to see it on a mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Burf.

You have to go to the ".android" folder. To find it, just open a terminal and write:

```
cd
cd .android/
```

After that, you need to modify the file adb_usb.ini (I recommend to back it up previously) and add the vendor ID after the last line, In this case, for Epson it is: 0x04B8.

It should look like this after that:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0xXXXX
0x04B8
```

Then you only have to save the file and run:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Remember that you need to enable de USB debugging in your device to allow adb to "see" it.

After this, your device should be listed with:

```
adb devices
```

Hope it helps.

Aernarion.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Add vendor ID(0x04B8) in ~usr/.android/adb_usb.ini

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x04B8
```

2)  Save the above adb_usb.ini file.

Followed by

```
A.  Bring up command prompt.
B.  Type “adb kill-server” then enter.
C.  Type “adb start-server” then enter.
D.  Type “adb devices” then enter.
E.  You should see BT-200 as one of the devices.
```