# How to get the Epson BT 200 (Moverio) listed with ADB (USB-Debugging Moverio on Ubuntu)

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb, epson

My Epson BT-200 does not get listed for adp when I execute the command:

```
adb devices
```

To fix that problem I followed the steps of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171205/usb-debugging-moverio-on-mac). Unfortunately without success.

```
lsusb
```

prints out the following line for my device:

```
Bus 002 Device 081: ID 04b8:0c06 Seiko Epson Corp.
```

So I edited my "/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules" file and now it looks like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0666", OWNER="tokam"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c06", MODE="0666", OWNER="tokam"
```

But the restarting of udev (and even my computer), replugging of the bt-200 usb-cable and the restart of the adb-server does not lead to a listed device.

**What can I do to get the device listed with adb?**

I checked on the device, USB-Debugging is enabled. It is turned on, and the password is entered, so it got mounted as a disc-drive.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Comment: Thanks I got it working by adding the vendor id to the adb_usb.ini

I first got that wrong because I searched for the file in the adb folder and not at ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

Now adb finds my device :)