# ADB driver not installing for BT Moverio 200

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, driver, windows-8.1

I get this error as it shows in the image. So basically, it won't install the adb driver onto my device. So when I open android studio, it doesnt show any traces of the glasses being a connected device.

I know this because I've tried with my phone and it will show my phone as a connected device on Android studio.

I've seen [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727627/how-to-get-the-epson-bt-200-moverio-listed-with-adb-usb-debugging-moverio-on) but they are just not helping since this is already included in [instructions I've been following](http://www.augmentedmarketing.ca/marketing/EpsonUSB_EN_6.pdf).

I am on a windows 8.1 laptop, should I try on ubuntu?

If I try it virtually on ubuntu will it be slow to install Android Studio and just to do things generally?

adb not working:

[image: adb not working]

Comment: I still couldnt get over this problem and am just using slide loading apk files to the glasses made from android studio with api 15 selected to do testing, so if anyone has an answer feel free to reply to this post thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may not help everyone but this fixed it for me (Windows 10 Enterprise using BT2000).

Working on the assumption that the android_winusb.inf file has been altered along with all other instructions in the BT-2000 developer guide[1]. 
These were the steps I took to install mine:

1. In device manager, right click to update drivers and choose browse computer
2. Instead of entering the path to the driver file here - instead click 'let me pick from a list'
3. Leave the left category on 'Google, Inc.' and find 'Android ADB Interface' on the right
   [image: Driver popup 1]
4. Click 'Have Disk' and enter the path to your android_winusb driver file here.
5. Choose Android ADB Interface again on the next screen and follow it through confirming that you want to update it on the warning pop up.
6. If you check your adb devices the glasses should show as '0123456789ABCDEF        device'

[1] Section 2.4 - https://tech.moverio.epson.com/en/bt-2000/1_0_4/developers_guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to get the glasses recognised as an adb. After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972658/adb-driver-and-windows-8-1?rq=1) , also [this](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH) and  [how to get ADB working in Windows for the Epson Moverio BT-200 by Dave ,](https://plus.google.com/+DaveMartinezsf/posts/5w5d7iccJ2P)  .

from first link Use  "Universal ADB (Android Debug Bridge) Driver for Windows": https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH  , install this driver on your computer.

Following advice of Dave, line I went on the [android studio site for android_winusb](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html) .then  you extract the Google USB Driver ZIP file and remember  the path location to the android_winusb.inf file.

search to device manager>look for device embt2>select update driver>select you want to select driver your self and select the  universal driver and samsung android device

then you have to enter the path of the driver which is the path location to the android_winusb.inf file from your downloads

click and finish to install.

the glasses should be listed as a samsung android device in device manager as a android adb device

If you open android studio, it should detect your glasses as an adb device and you can run apps on it